# How to Exclude a selected and highlighted post from displaying among rest of the posts

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have custom post type of doctors. When the name is clicked it will take to the single page of the doctor. Below there is a small div which displays a number of posts. I dont want the post which is already displayed at the top to be at the bottom.

this is the code i have done:

```
<?php foreach($dr as $doc){ ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($doc->ID);?>" class="img-reposive img-circle dc-img mb50" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="dr-single-box">
                    <h3 class="dr-single-tile"><?php echo $doc->post_title; ?></h3>
                    <div class="sub-tile"><?php echo get_post_meta($doc->ID,'Department',true); ?></div>
                    <div class="dc-single-social">
<p><?php echo $doc->post_content; ?></p>
                    <a href="appointment" class="btn btn-default mt30 mb50">make an appointment</a>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h3 class="mb10">Qualifications</h3>
                            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($doc->ID,'Qualifications',true); ?></p>        
                        </div>
```

the bottom portion looks like this :

```
<?php $arg=array('post_type'=>'doctors','post_status'=>'publish','posts_per_page'=>4,'offset'=>1) ;
$doctor_data=get_posts($arg); 
/*var_dump($doctor_data);*/ ?>
<div class="lightbg ptb80">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <h1 class="heading-title">Doctors</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($doctor_data as $doctor) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="dc-style-box">
                   <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($doctor->ID); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Doctor 1" />
                    <div class="dc-style-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        </ul> 
                        <h5><a href="<?php echo $doctor->guid; ?>"><?php echo $doctor->post_title; ?></a></h5>
                        <span><?php echo get_post_meta($doctor->ID,'Department',true);?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

can anyone shed some light to guide me ? ?

Comment: so do you wish to show random posts in that bottom section?

Comment: yes random posts from the same post type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$cur = get_the_ID();
$arg=array('post_type'=>'doctors','post_status'=>'publish','posts_per_page'=>4,'offset'=>1, 'post__not_in' => $cur) ;
$doctor_data=get_posts($arg); 
/*var_dump($doctor_data);*/ ?>
<div class="lightbg ptb80">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <h1 class="heading-title">Doctors</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($doctor_data as $doctor) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="dc-style-box">
                   <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($doctor->ID); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Doctor 1" />
                    <div class="dc-style-inner">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        </ul> 
                        <h5><a href="<?php echo $doctor->guid; ?>"><?php echo $doctor->post_title; ?></a></h5>
                        <span><?php echo get_post_meta($doctor->ID,'Department',true);?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Hi, You should add '`post__not_in`' to exclude current post to be fetched in second loop. Try this code.  Let me know if you need any more assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you wish to display random posts therefore use below $arg instead of yours.

```
$arg = array('post_type'=>'doctors',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=>4,
        'offset'=>1,
        'orderby'   => 'rand'
      );
```